# How can I simplify this class method?

Tags: ruby, class, oop

I have a class that has 50 random people with random scores, stored in an array of hashes:

```
def initialize
    # adding fake names and numbers
    require 'faker'
    @people = []
    (1..50).each do
      @people << { name: Faker::Name.first_name, score: Faker::Number.between(1, 1000).to_i }
    end
end
```

The `top` method in particular (below) will return the top N people in a string with their score. Being a little newer to ruby, I think there might be a way to make this simpler. Here's the method:

```
def top(number=10)
    top_people = @people.group_by { |person| person[:score] }
                        .sort_by { |key, value| -key }     # largest -> smallest
                        .first(number)
                        .map(&:last)
                        .flatten
                        .map { |person| "#{person[:name]} (#{person[:score]})" }
                        .join(", ")
    puts "The top #{number} are here: #{top_people}"
end
```

For reference, using Ruby 2.3.3

Comment: A> write automated tests for that, so changing the code is safer. B> `"#{person[:name]} (#{person[:score]})"` could be `'%{name} (%{score})' % person`. And C> don't write a run-on statement. Use `top_people = top_people.sort_by...`, in separate lines.

Comment: @Phlip Is repeating `top_people = ...` really idiomatic? I'd consider that code smell because all of the intermediate lines wouldn't really be `top_people`, they'd be `sorted_groups`, `top_groups`, etc. Only after the flatten do you actually have `top_people`

Comment: I'm maintaining a project where someone crammed everything together into one statement, without intermediate variables, and lots of newline-dots \n. like yours. Please don't get me started! C-;

Comment: @Phlip I'm referring to the local variable names. See my updated answer.

Comment: `(1..50).each` could be `50.times`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a good idea to mix business logic (how to get the best people) with output (how to display a list of people). And you can slightly simplify by combining the sort_by/group_by and using `flat_map`:

```
class MyClass
  def top number=10
    top_groups = @people.group_by { |person| person[:score] }.max_by(number, &:first)
    top_groups.flat_map(&:last)
  end

  def self.show_people people
    people.map { |person| "%{name} (%{score})" % person }.join(", ")
  end
end

some_class = MyClass.new
top_people = some_class.top 10
puts "The top #{top_people.size} people are #{MyClass.show_people(top_people)}"
```

Comment: You can go a step further and turn the people into their own objects that know how to display themselves.

Comment: Consider using `max_by(top_number) {...}`.

Answer (score 1):

[Be Welcoming](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/?cb=1) is our new moto, so here goes...

When you are asking a question please make sure it is a complete and functional question. e.g. *"I have a class that has 50 random people with random scores, stored in an array of hashes:[...]The top method in particular  will return the top N people in a string with their score."*

Please provide us with a class then:

```
# require your dependencies outside of the class 
# this is where they will end up anyway and it makes it easier for us
# to find them
require 'faker'

class Scoreboard
   def initialize
     # adding fake names and numbers

     @people = []
     (1..50).each do
       @people << { name: Faker::Name.first_name, 
                    score: Faker::Number.between(1, 1000).to_i }
     end
  end
  def top(number=10)
    top_people = @people.group_by { |person| person[:score] }
                    .sort_by { |key, value| -key }     # largest -> smallest
                    .first(number)
                    .map(&:last)
                    .flatten
                    .map { |person| "#{person[:name]} (#{person[:score]})" }
                    .join(", ")
    puts "The top #{number} are here: #{top_people}"
  end
end
```

Now let's talk about what you are actually doing here in `Scoreboard#top`

Steps:

- Group into a `Hash` by score
- Sort by Score (in reverse)
- Take the first n groupings
- Map dropping the the scores
- Flatten the `Array`
- map again into a String of name (score)
- join with commas
- print them all on the same line

This seems like a bit of overkill. The let's try a different solution by finding the cut off instead

```
def cut(n=10) 
  @people.map {|p| p[:score]}.uniq.sort.last(n).first
end
```

Now we know the smallest score we will accept so top now just needs those `people`

```
def top(n=10)
  top_people = @people.select {|p| p[:score] >= cut(n) }
               .sort_by {|p| -p[:score]}
               .map { |person| "#{person[:name]} (#{person[:score]})" }
  puts "The top #{n} are here: #{top_people.join(',')}"
end
```

Now that seems a bit cleaner but `People` should not be relegated to a dictionary (we have feelings after all) so let's make them a real `Object` (btw objectifying people is still wrong in real life). Since they are simple creatures having just a `first_name` and a `score` a `Struct` will do just fine.

```
Person = Struct.new(:name, :score)
```

This essentially creates an object that looks like this

```
class Person 
  attr_accessor :name, :score 
  def initialize(name,score)
    @name = name
    @score = score
  end
end
```

Now we can create our people like so

```
def initialize
  # we will use Enumerable#map rather than initializing an Array
  # and pushing into it
  @people = (1..50).map do 
    Person.new(Faker::Name.first_name, 
        Faker::Number.between(1, 1000).to_i)
  end
end
```

Now rather than `Hash#[]` access we have methods for `score` and `name` so we can use some `Symbol#to_proc` sugar (don't worry about this right now but feel free to look into it as it is very ruby idiomatic)

```
def cut(n=10) 
  @people.map(&:score).uniq.sort.last(n).first
end
def top(n=10)
 top_people = @people.select {|p| p.score >= cut(n) }
              .sort_by(&:score).reverse
              .map { |person| "#{person.name} (#{person.score})" }
 puts "The top #{n} are here: #{top_people.join(',')}"
end
```

We are almost there now but this `"#{person.name} (#{person.score})"` seems silly since those are the only attributes anyway so let's just make that the default representation of a `Person` by defining `to_s` for our `Person`

```
Person = Struct.new(:name, :score) do 
   def to_s
      "#{name} (#{score})"
   end
end
```

Now we have

```
def top(n=10)
  top_people = @people.select {|p| p.score >= cut(n) }
               .sort_by(&:score).reverse
end
```

Also since `puts` returns `nil` and you can handle the display elsewhere I have removed the `puts` statement. Since you already know `n` from outside the call I would suggest something like:

```
n = 12
puts "The top #{n} people are:" 
puts Scoreboard.new.top(n)
```

Ooh so much cleaner now. Hope you enjoyed the answer and learned something along the way. [Full Example](https://repl.it/@engineersmnky/PastGummyEquipment)

Comment: hey - thanks for this! just got back from vacation, i did learn a lot from this post :) i did make 2 slight modifications, since i think your answer was accounting for people with unique scores and not for people with the same score:

1) removed the `.uniq` method from inside of `cut`, and 2) added `.first(n)` to the `top_people` to get a true top n of everyone. i also added `n = @people.length unless @people.length > n` to the beginning to `top` in case the user were to ask for a top n that is greater than the size of people

Comment: @Mike removing `uniq` makes sense although it is now different than your original implementation. As for the `first` comment how do you determine top if people have the same score. For example 5 people tied for 7th who gets cut from the list. Third `first` and `last` already handle numbers larger than the size of the `Array` for you so no need e.g. `[1,2].first(10) #=> [1,2]`

Comment: i imagine it like an arcade cabinet scoreboard - there's a hard limit on how many are displayed (of course usually sorted by another parameter like time acquired but i'm not looking to add that right now).    RE: adding a line to the top of `top` - you're right, i just stepped through everything again and it's not needed. i had added it originally before refactoring to your suggestions but just didn't take it out, went on vacation, and then refactored and kept it in

Answer (score 1):

I tried to improve also other things. I miss a bit more context, but responding your question as a theoretical exercise, this is what I would do:

```
 require 'faker'

 class ScoredPerson
  attr_reader :name
  attr_reader :score

  def initialize
    @name = Faker::Name.first_name
    @score = Faker::Number.between(1, 1000).to_i
  end
end

class TopPeople
  attr_accessor :people

  def initialize
    @people = 50.times.map do
      ScoredPerson.new
    end.sort_by { |p| p.score }.reverse
  end

  def top(number=10)
    people.first(number)
      .map { |p| "#{p.name} (#{p.score})"}.join(", ")
  end
end
```

- create an **ordered** list of people (at the very beginning). That will prevent to order on each call to the `top` method.
- create a `ScoredPerson` class to encapsulate the logic of an scored person.